# Allow colliders with rigidbodies to intersect each other

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am making a car game. My cars are colliding, but I don't want the cars to collide - I want the cars to go inside of the other cars, which have both a rigidbody and a collider. Is there a way to allow my cars' colliders to ignore each other for physics interactions?

Comment: Not entirely certain what you want here, but if you don't want colliders to interact, put them on [separate physics layers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) and turn off interactions between the layers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to project settings, physics and take a look on the matrix.

With this matrix you can exclude cars colliding with each other giving them proper layer and unchecking this layer to colide with itself.

Comment: @BerkayÖzdemir Please be sure to accept an answer if it adequately solves your problem - that way, it signals to others that the question is answered. Thanks!